# ValueError: file descriptor out of range in select() in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

After one of the recent updates of py2neo we are seeing a lot of randomly appearing errors saying 
**ValueError: file descriptor out of range in select()** we are using **py2neo** to connect to remote neo4j instance.

```
client_identifier = request.args.get('tribes_client_id')
graph_obj = generic_helpers.get_graph_object(client_identifier) # <- returns py2neo instance
graph_transaction = graph_obj.begin() # <- this is the line causing the exception
```

Below is stack trace of the exception being raised

> **Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app      response = self.full_dispatch_request()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise      raise value    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request      rv = self.dispatch_request()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request      return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint    File "/srv/neo4j_maintenance_routes.py", line 116, in get_words_list_for_lookup      graph_transaction = graph_obj.begin()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/database.py", line 353, in begin      return Transaction(self, autocommit)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/database.py", line 781, in __init__      self.transaction = self.connector.begin()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/internal/connectors.py", line 297, in begin      tx = self.pool.acquire()    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 715, in acquire      return self.acquire_direct(self.address)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 608, in acquire_direct      connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py2neo/internal/connectors.py", line 227, in connector      encrypted=cx_data["secure"], **kwargs)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 972, in connect      raise last_error    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 964, in connect      connection = _handshake(s, address, der_encoded_server_certificate, **config)    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 898, in _handshake      ready_to_read, _, _ = select((s,), (), (), 1)  ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()**

```
py2neo -> version 4.3.0  
python -> version 3.7.3  
neo4j -> version (Enterprise 3.5.3)
```

Thing to notice is we aren't getting these errors every time we are creating a new transaction but on random times and it automatically gets fixed after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

I also come across this issue occasionally. The different thing is, I am implementing `neo4j-python-driver (1.7.6)`.

```sh
File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 444, in run
    self._connect()
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 383, in _connect
    self._connection = self._acquirer(access_mode)
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 715, in acquire
    return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 608, in acquire_direct
    connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neo4j/__init__.py", line 232, in connector
    return connect(address, **dict(config, **kwargs))
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 972, in connect
    raise last_error
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 964, in connect
    connection = _handshake(s, address, der_encoded_server_certificate, **config)
  File "/home/my/anaconda3/envs/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/neobolt/direct.py", line 898, in _handshake
    ready_to_read, _, _ = select((s,), (), (), 1)
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

After I rerun the same code, nothing happened and the program worked well. I think this issue is probably caused by multiple 'login in' action of the same user. When I still in the process of accessing the neo4j database in the browser and use that account to fetch data with neo4j-python-driver at the same time, this error could happened. However, sometimes it seems that it just happened in that way regardless of the fact that I did nothing but run the code.

Extra Info:

- Neo4j Graph Database: 3.5 community version